Change colour of a polygon based on a points colour in arcade
I have 2 layers of data, which both have the same values, one point, one polygon.
The point layer contains 160,000 points representing 16 areas over the course of 30 years and is time enabled. The polygon layer holds the 16 physical areas and they are linked by a name field.
I'd like to change the colour of each polygon, every time their associated point colour changes as it cycles through the time associated time field that has a 'theme associated with it.
I have tried long and hard to find out how to do it, so wanted to ask the forum if anyone else has a solution?

I think if you shared a sample of your data people will have something to explore with? Also sounds like you have your points changing colour with time, what exactly did you do to achieve that. Screen shots would be help rather than a block of text.

Within ArcGIS Online, this is not possible. Even creating more complex arcade symbology, you cannot symbolize any layer based on data existing in another. They exclude this from the profile so performance is not destroyed.

Yes, I have been trying to do this on AGOL, no luck, works in ArcGIS Pro.
I have 5700 polygons each with a unique date and value I want to colour it on.  Performance is poor, so I thought adding one polygon and simply colouring it as the same as a point, and simply having 5700 points scrolling through a timeline would improve performance  Works well on ArcPro,.
